# Dependency order between multiple avro schema files

Tags: java, avro

I have multiple `.avsc` files, that require a certain type, say `foo`:

```
{ "type":"fixed","size":16, "name": "foo"}
```

examples:

a.avsc:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "A",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": ["null", "foo"],
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string",
    }
  ]
}
```

b.avsc:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "B",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": ["null", "foo"],
    },
    {
      "name": "size",
      "type": "int",
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that if I put foo.avsc in a separate file (or in either of these two files), avroCodeGen tool needs to make sure it is processed first (is it possible? how?) otherwise I get  `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Undefined name: "foo"` and if I define it every time I need it like below, I get `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Can't redefine: foo`

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "B",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": ["null", { "type":"fixed","size":16, "name": "foo"}],
    },
    {
      "name": "size",
      "type": "int",
    }
  ]
}

{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "A",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": ["null", { "type":"fixed","size":16, "name": "foo"}],
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string",
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any workaround for this? (The actual records are more than two, and a lot more complex so putting everything in one file unfortunately is not an option.)

p.s: I'm using these two libraries:
`"org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7"` and `"org.apache.avro:avro-tools:1.7.5"`